# Change android input method for WebView

Tags: android, android-input-method

I have a WebView that loads a webpage with a form and would like to use the most basic keyboard possible in order to conserve screen real estate if they are using the onscreen keyboard as their input method.  I would also like to disable things like word suggestions in the onscreen keyboard.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the input method, anywhere -- only users can change their input method.

In terms of disabling search suggestions, I haven't seen any hooks to change that behavior that are exposed from `WebView`, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add some attributes to the HTMl component that will make what you want. 
This works in the Android devices I have tested (Samsung Galaxy 4 and Nexus 7), but I would not be surprised if this does not work in other devices.

```
<input autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"> test

<textarea spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off"> test </textarea>
```