# Is there an equivalent to Android's textNoSuggestions in HTML?

Tags: android, html, user-interface, web, input

If I have an input element of type "text", is there a way to prevent the Android keyboard from making suggestions when inputting to that element?

In a native Android app this would be "textNoSuggestions", but is there an equivalent for the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you have the attribute `autocomplete="off|on"`

so, for instance, you use:

```
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
```

and also can add other, like

```
<input autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
```

With this, you shouldnt get the field dropdown with the browser suggestions based on input history, but the keyboard is still giving its own suggestions (thats on the inputmethod side, and not in the browser side).

For this, probably you can only try with some patches, that i wont recommend. I havent find any clean solution, and some time ago @CommonsWare [said in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6483426/2357411) that he hasn't seen anything, so if there has not been any change in this time, probably this wont be possible.

Comment: FYI, the type="email" part is also required. I was already trying autocomplete="off" but it wasn't working because I had type="text".

Comment: In fact, it's just the type="email" part that turns it off. The autocomplete="off" doesn't seem to be needed:
http://jsfiddle.net/qJWMR/4/

Comment: probably depending on the system. I would keep it, since it what the docs say: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: im trying your jsfiddle, and i dont have suggesion with or without it in chrome, i guess it depends on many things, browser configuration, actual history, and so on. I think the best is the use the two of them, the tyoe=email and the autocomplete attribute as the documentation says :)

Comment: Actually, this answer doesn't work out. Having type="email" means that Chrome on Android does validation on that field and doesn't allow the form to submit unless it has an "@" in it.

Comment: Are you sure it doesnt work for you? look at what w3c says:

"The autocomplete attribute specifies whether or not an input field should have autocomplete enabled.

Autocomplete allows the browser to predict the value. When a user starts to type in a field, the browser should display options to fill in the field, based on earlier typed values.

Note: The autocomplete attribute works with the following <input> types: text, search, url, tel, email, password, datepickers, range, and color."

Comment: Yeah, try this on an Android device: http://jsfiddle.net/qJWMR/1/
The Chrome bug is here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303883

Actually, there is a way to get it pretty close using type="email", though. I'll edit your answer.